# 7zs.sfx unsupported method

Tags: batch-file, 7zip, sfx

I have setup project that I need to sfx him .

first I zip the .msi and .exe files :

```
%path7zip% a "%~dp0% %setup.7z" "%~dp0% %Output\Setup\*"
```

that work fine .

then I sfx the 7z file :

```
copy /b %path7zs% + "%~dp0% %config.txt" + "%~dp0% %Setup.7z" "%~dp0% %     
Output\Setup\MySetup.exe"
```

my config file is :

```
;!@Install@!UTF-8!
Title="my title"
Progress="no"
GUIFlags=""
OverwriteMode="0"
InstallPath="%TEMP%"
ExtractPathText="Select extraction path"
ExtractPathTitle="my title"
ExtractTitle="Extracting"
ExtractDialogText=""
ExtractCancelText="Abort"
RunProgram="\"%%T\\setup.exe\""
;!@InstallEnd@!
```

I get the MySetup.exe file but when I try to open it I get :
7-zip: unsupported method.
Any ideas?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use [7zsd.sfx](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HwDQ2rHTz5Hoilv7Wb3cHc4fNySyUk50) instead of 7zs.sfx

You can also use this file to fix a corrupted exe that says "unsupported method", without adding the config.txt, like that:

`copy /b 7zSD.sfx + corruptedExe fixedExe.exe`

Answer (score 1):

captain_majid's solution worked for me. I also found in [this post](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45798/thread/ea0ec779/) at SourceForge the suggestion to use `-mm=lzma` when generating the 7z file, which worked as well.

Would be nice to know the difference, though.