# Self extracting archive (EXE) for Windows

Tags: zip, windows-installer, exe, php-ziparchive

I'm looking for an easy way to create a **self extracting archive** (EXE) on Microsoft Windows platforms. I know that there is a built-in tool *IExpress.exe*, but that has a wizard style UI and I need a "silent" tool, which can be called by scripts. It should be:

- Scriptable (Windows shell script or Ant build file)
- **Free for commercial use**
- Optionally unpack in a temporary folder or ask the user where to put the unpacked files
- Nice to have: Auto launch an executable in the archive after unpack
- No knick-knack like creating desktop icons, start menu entries, etc. Just plain unpack functionality into a named folder.

Comment: Just a heads-up: whatever tool you use, remember to try to upload the resulting EXE to https://www.virustotal.com to check for any false positive malware issues.

Answer (score 2):

***Tools List***: I assume you have already checked stuff like this? **https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-extracting_archive**.

***iExpress***: This tool has some severe [security vulnerabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IExpress#Security). Don't use it please. It is tragic to deal with if your clients and customers face these problems. A wrong turn to make as they say.

***7-Zip***: I wrote this answer some time back relating to problems seen when creating 7-Zip archives: [Error Creating a 7-zip installer package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51757086/error-creating-a-7-zip-installer-package/51757384#51757384). Although 7-Zip seems solid overall, I get the feeling that the self-extraction parts is not prioritized (as of yet). Or basically just not finished.

***WinZip & WinRAR***: I guess WinZip or WinRAR would be the most common and most tested solutions, without being an expert on the subject. I always prefer [**"real" setup tools**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50229840/129130) since these are generally much better tested than self-extracting archives due to their "heavy rotation" - plenty of use. They are also pretty good at running in minimum dependency scenarios - or on "normal systems" - without too many weird dependencies. And they appear more recognizable by anti-virus scanners and hence limiting the problem of false positives. I also find them easier for end users to deal with.

---

Can we ask why you need this to be self-extracting? Zip support has been built into Windows for quite some time? Just asking, I am sure there are very good reasons.